# jooq to spring integration

Tags: spring, jooq

I tried to use jooq in my spring project, but code from manual doesn't want to work.

```
<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
<constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionProvider" />
<constructor-arg index="1"><null /></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index="2"><value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">H2</value></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index="3"><null /></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index="4"><null /></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But DefaultConfiguration has no parameters in constructor.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace into your post, for a full overview and better explanation of what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other, non-public, constructors in [that class](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/DefaultConfiguration.java). I suspect you need some additional properties (and that the manual wasn't updated to reflect the changes).

```
<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionProvider" />
    <constructor-arg index="1"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="4"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="5"><value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">H2</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="6"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="7"><null /></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Whoops, nice catch. Will be fixed immediately with [#2816](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2816)

Comment: this doesn't work for me either. which version of jooq should i be using? i have 3.2.0